# How to add Element between react children with Some condition?

Tags: reactjs

I need to add element between each children when some props values satisfied 
how to do that

"only add element if the prop value is space is true"

now i did like this

```
const style={
height:"10px"
}


if(this.props.space){
style.width=30;
}

render(){
return(

{React.Children.map(children, (child, i) => {
            return (
              <React.Fragment>
                <span style={style}></span>
                <React.Fragment>{child}</React.Fragment>
              </React.Fragment>

            );
          })}
)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So is it the span you only want if space is true?

Then you could do something like this

```
{React.Children.map(children, (child, i) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            {this.props.space && <span style={style}></span>}
            <React.Fragment>{child}</React.Fragment>
          </React.Fragment>

        );
      })}
```

The concept is explained here https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

It works because `true && expression` will evaluate to expression, and `false && expression` will evaluate to false.

Comment: I have already tried this i giving two span on top and bottom

Answer (score 0):

Span is an inline element and doens't take `width and height`. You can instead return a div element conditionally and and align the child and the div element horizontally like

```
function App({ children, space }) {
  const style = {
    height: "10px",
    width: "30px",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    display: "inlin"
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, i) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
              {space ? <div style={style} /> : null}
              <div>{child}</div>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App space>
    <div>Hello</div>
  </App>,
  rootElement
);
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mq8p6422qy)

However conditionally adding an element to provide space to the left doesn't seem to be a good idea. You can instead add class and add property like margin-left or add a style

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, i) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
              <div style={{marginLeft: '30px'}}>{child}</div>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```